# Custom loss function's results does not match with the inbuilt loss function's result

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have implemented a custom binary cross entropy loss function in tensorflow. To test this I had compared it with the inbuilt binary cross entropy loss function in Tensorflow. But, I got very different results in both cases. I am unable to understand this behaviour.

```
def custom_loss(eps,w1,w2):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        ans = -1*(w1*y_true*tf.log(y_pred+eps) + w2*(1-y_true)*tf.log(y_pred+eps))
        return ans
    return loss
```

I had set eps to 1e-6, w1=1 and w2=1. The loss dropped to very small values when I used my implementation of the loss function. Whereas, there was a steady drop while using the inbuilt loss function in tensorflow.

Edit:
Here are the outputs:

1: Using the custom implementation:

1/650 [..............................] - ETA: 46:37 - loss: 0.8810 - acc: 0.50

2/650 [..............................] - ETA: 41:27 - loss: 0.4405 - acc: 0.40

3/650 [..............................] - ETA: 39:38 - loss: 0.2937 - acc: 0.41

4/650 [..............................] - ETA: 38:44 - loss: 0.2203 - acc: 0.45

5/650 [..............................] - ETA: 38:13 - loss: 0.1762 - acc: 0.46

6/650 [..............................] - ETA: 37:47 - loss: 0.1468 - acc: 0.42

7/650 [..............................] - ETA: 37:29 - loss: 0.1259 - acc: 0

2. Using the built in loss function with eps=1e-7.

1/650 [..............................] - ETA: 48:15 - loss: 2.4260 - acc: 0.31

2/650 [..............................] - ETA: 42:09 - loss: 3.1842 - acc: 0.46

3/650 [..............................] - ETA: 40:10 - loss: 3.4615 - acc: 0.47

4/650 [..............................] - ETA: 39:06 - loss: 3.9737 - acc: 0.45

5/650 [..............................] - ETA: 38:28 - loss: 4.5173 - acc: 0.47

6/650 [..............................] - ETA: 37:58 - loss: 5.1865 - acc: 0.45

7/650 [..............................] - ETA: 37:41 - loss: 5.8239 - acc: 0.43

8/650 [..............................] - ETA: 37:24 - loss: 5.6979 - acc: 0.46

9/650 [..............................] - ETA: 37:12 - loss: 5.5973 - acc: 0.47

The input is an image from the MURA dataset. To keep the test uniform same images are passed in both the tests.

Comment: Please provide your input, the expected output, and the actual output. Also I believe binary cross entropy in tf uses eps=1e-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a slight error in your implementation.

You have:

```
ans = -1*(w1*y_true*tf.log(y_pred+eps) + w2*(1-y_true)*tf.log(y_pred + eps))
```

Whereas, I think you were aiming for:

```
ans = -1*(w1*y_true*tf.log(y_pred+eps) + w2*(1-y_true)*tf.log(1 - y_pred + eps))
```

Generally we also take the average of this loss so that makes our implementation:

```py
def custom_loss(eps,w1,w2):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        ans = -1*(w1*y_true*tf.log(y_pred+eps) + w2*(1-y_true)*tf.log(1-y_pred+eps))
        return tf.reduce_mean(ans)
    return loss
```

which we can now test against the out of the box implementation:

```
y_true = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2])
y_pred = tf.constant([0.11, 0.19])

custom_loss(y_true, y_pred)                         # == 0.41316
tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) # == 0.41317
```

and find that the results match to many decimal places (I can't account for the small difference - maybe a different epsilon value? - but I guess such a small difference is negligible)

Comment: I should just mention that i did NOT see this error when I was looking at your previous question! I'm pleased you wrote a new question but it I had of noticed it before I certainly would have mentioned it then! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Stewart R. This has cleared my understanding about loss functions in machine learning.